# rename & replace characters windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

x

Not success in rename the file in windows batch script.
please kindly advise. appreciate the help

```
set "source=C:\Users\Processed"

    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /s /m /l /c:"949010" "%source%\*"') 
        do (
        set "fname=%%A"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set "fname=!fname:{=!"
            ren %%A "!fname!"
            endlocal &
        copy /y "%source%\%fname%" "C:\Users\949010" )
```

Comment: What is the expected file name after this script runs?

Comment: I see that you have the line `set "fname=!fname:{=%"`. Did you mean to say `set "fname=!fname:{=!"` instead?

Comment: Also, `ren` requires two arguments - the original filename and name to change the file to.

Comment: the expected file name after script runs is from {0036988}151028085048ICTEST881.RAW to 0036988151028085048ICTEST881.RAW

I made changes to set "fname=!fname:{=!"

Comment: @SomethingDark  do I need to use ren if set "fname=!fname:{=%" ???

Comment: You need to use `ren %%A "!fname!"`

Comment: edit and update, above, still not workable

Comment: You do not need to switch delayed expansion *on* and *off* within the `for /F` loop, you could also place `setlocal`/`endlocal` _before_/_after_ the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 small errors in your code *when I reviewed it!* BTW it is a bad idea to modify the original code with no advice of what you did *in the question itself*...

- The `fname` variable must contain just *the name and extension* of the file, so `~nx` modifier must be used in `%%A` variable.
- The `do` clause must be placed in the same line of the `for` command.
- In the `ren` command both names *should* be enclosed in quotes (not an error in *this* case).
- The `&` sign is used to separate two commands *in the same line*. It *should* be a command after the `&`.
- *All references* to a variable that changes inside `for` loop must be enclosed in exclamation-marks.
- The `endlocal` command must be placed *after* the last variable with exclamation-marks.

I also modified the justification of the code in the standard way.

This is the corrected code:

```
set "source=C:\Users\Processed"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /s /m /l /c:"949010" "%source%\*"') do (
    set "fname=%%~nxA"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "fname=!fname:{=!"
    ren "%%A" "!fname!"
    copy /y "%source%\!fname!" "C:\Users\949010"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Always at your service! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
set "source=C:\Users\Processed"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /s /m /l /c:"949010" "%source%\*"') do (
    set "fname=%%~nxA"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "fname=!fname:{=!"
    ren "%%A" "!fname!"
    copy /y "%%A" "C:\Users\949010"
    endlocal
)
```